# Clang preprocessor flag for Objective-C block support?

Tags: objective-c, block, clang

What's the Clang preprocessor flag for Objective-C block support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
__BLOCKS__
```

This dumps all the compiler defined macros:

```
clang -dM -E - < /dev/null
```

Comment: Where is -dM documented?  I'm not finding it in the man page nor in the User manual on the web site.

Comment: clang intends to be gcc command-line option compatible.  -dM is documented for gcc at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options

Comment: note that for non-unix platforms, if `touch` is available, you can do `touch foo.h` followed by `clang -dM -E foo.h`

Comment: can somebody explain the `__BLOCKS__` macro to me? I saw it on inserting `__block` but its not explained inside xCode.